# Reducing space before chapter works with english but not with hungarian babel package

Tags: spacing, chapters, babel, etoolbox, hungarian

I write my thesis recently and I want to reduce the spaces before chapters. I find the solution, but it isn't working for me with `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}`

I use the following codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% Switch between these babel languages to see the difference
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Reducing space before chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the code

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

immediately *after* `\begin{document}` in order for the patch to take effect. A more formal approach would be to tie into the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) hook `afterextras`:

```
\makeatletter
\AddBabelHook{patches}{afterextras}{%
  \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
}
\makeatother
```

The reason here is that certain languages reformats the sectional units inside the `l`anguage `d`efinition `f`ile (or `.ldf`), and executes these as part of an "event" called `extras` (specifically, for `magyar` this is contained within [`magyar.ldf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/hungarian/magyar.ldf) would be `\extrasmagyar`). So, even though the `\patchcmd` from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) may work where placed inside the preamble, or even `\AtBeginDocument`, it's overwritten by `babel` during the `extras` event. The `afterextras` event is therefore an appropriate location to patch.

Comment: It seems like `report.cls` is reloaded around the time `\AtBeginDocument` is executed, causing the patch that was successfully made in the preamble to be overwritten.

Comment: Or enclosing the two `\patchcmd` instructions in `\AtBeginDocument`, which is better.

Comment: @egreg: Did you try it? :)

Comment: Oh, right! I hate the `magyar.ldf` module. `;-)` Actually, the way the module works makes it rather fragile and sometimes incompatible with classes or packages.